# Change value of var if element exists

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to change the value of my var if h6#area doesn't exist. It's not working in my code.

```js
var selection = document.querySelector('h6#area').length;

if (selection) {
  var areaText2 = document.querySelector("h6#area").textContent;
} else {
  var areaText2 = 'in the area';
}
```

If the h6#area doesn't exist, I want the var to equal the text string "in the area". It will be going into the code below:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $("#message").val("Lead origin: " + currentURL);
  $(".rg-modal-contact h2").text('Buy a home in ' + areaText2 + ' with us');
  $("#message").after('<h3 class="agent">Are you working with an agent?</h3>');
  $("h3.agent").after('<select class="agent" name="agent" id="agent"><option value="No">No</option><option value="Yes">Yes</option></select>');
  $("select#agent").after('<h3 class="address">What is your price range?</h3>');
  $("h3.address").after('<select class="agent" name="pricerange" id="pricerange"><option value="$50,000-$250,000">$50,000-$250,000</option><option value="$250,000-$500,000">$250,000-$500,000</option><option value="$500,000-$800,000">$500,000-$800,000</option><option value="$800,000-$1,000,000">$800,000-$1,000,000</option><option value="$1,000,000-$1,500,000">$1,000,000-$1,500,000</option><option value="$1,500,000+">$1,500,000+</option></select>');
  $("select#pricerange").after('<h3 class="addcomments">Any specific needs?</h3>');
  $("h3.addcomments").after('<textarea id="message2" class="comments" rows="5" placeholder="At least 1,500sqft, at least 3 beds, etc. More info helps us help you better!"></textarea>');
}, 1);
```

Comment: Long story. I have to add elements with jquery. It's on this page: [link](https://www.bothellhomes.com/neighborhoods/mays-pond/) - right now there is no h6 on the page for testing. Still not working.

Comment: Open the browser console, look at the error messages. If `querySelector` doesn't find anything it returns null which doesn't have a length property.

Comment: So if it's null how do I set the if statement to check if it's null instead?

Comment: uh.. remove the .length and `if(selection === null)`? or just keep it as `if(selection)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the length of the elements as so (using `jquery`):

```
var areaText2;
if ($("#area").length) { 
  areaText2 = document.querySelector("#area").textContent;
} else {
  areaText2 = "the area";
}
```

Found your error! The var areaText2 does not exist beyond the if else block, you need to define it like `var areaText2` before the if.

Comment: Okay, try removing the h6 before #area, I edited it. What does the console show?

Comment: Yea still not working. I posted full links above in a different comment. So strange.

Comment: I think I got your error, see my edited post/answer

Comment: `var` isn't block scoped.

Comment: Ohk, @KevinBoroumand please add ``console.log(areaText2);`` after the else portion and tell what is it logging

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
    var selection = $('h6#area').length;
    if (selection) {
        var areaText2 = document.querySelector("h6#area").textContent;
    } else {
        var areaText2 = 'in the area';
    }
```

Comment: Full page: [link](https://www.bothellhomes.com/neighborhoods/mays-pond/) - Full JS: [link](https://u.realgeeks.media/lookinwa/js/listingresultsheader.js) - see line 360 where code for this starts thank you!

Comment: @KevinBoroumand But that link *doesn't* have this code. You only have `var areaText2 = document.querySelector("h6#area").textContent;` on line 363 which again will throw an error when the element doesn't exist.

Comment: Oh wow. I think the AWS server for s3 browser is lagging. I've been working on this for hours, it hasn't changed since and I've uploaded the file many times. whoops!!!